# What value for @SuppressWarnings do I use to suppress the "Can be private" warning?

Tags: java, android-studio, suppress-warnings

I keep getting annoyed by the "Can be private" warning, however my `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` will not work in that case. So, is there a `@SuppressWarnings` for that?

**What I've tried:**

`@SuppressWarnings("all")` but that's not what I want.

**Note:** I am using Android Studio

Comment: Add the `@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")` annotation to your class.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

It is best to simply disable this inspection, either for your whole project or for a specific class. Put your cursor on the warning and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up the following menu, which allows you to disable it:

[image: Disable inspection]

If you **really** want to use `@SuppressWarnings` you can choose the `Suppress for class` option from the dialog above. This will add the following annotation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
```

Comment: I am using IntelliJ 2017.1, but while the first lightbulb menu appears, I don't get the popout where I can `suppress for class`, etc. When clicking `Make 'package-private'` it immediately refactors.

Comment: @ArnoldSchrijver click the arrow instead of the option, or use your navigation buttons to navigate to the menu

Comment: Why would disabling inspection for the whole class be better than suppressing a warning for one function?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `@Suppress("MemberVisibilityCanBePrivate")` annotation